# Unable to add Ubuntu Precise (12) repositories to Ubuntu 18 (Bionic Beaver)

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, update-manager

Due to several reasons I'm trying to install a `glusterfs-client` version 3.2.5 on a Ubuntu 18.04.

This `glusterfs-client` version 3.2.5 is included on the `Ubuntu Precise` packages.

So I add these two lines to `sources.list`:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted universe multiverse
```

... then run `apt-get update`, and I get

```
W: GPG error: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise Release' is not signed.
```

okay, so I add the key:

```
root@myserver:/home/ubuntu# apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 40976EAF437D05B5
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.NFkm9FMqma/gpg.1.sh --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 40976EAF437D05B5
gpg: key 40976EAF437D05B5: 59 signatures not checked due to missing keys
gpg: key 40976EAF437D05B5: public key "Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
```

... run the `apt-get update` again, and I get the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise Release: The following signatures were invalid: 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5
```

Can someone tell me what is going on?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's the `glusterfs-client` package, not the `glusterfs` itself. I edited the post.

Comment: And then why not [the package from bionic universe](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/admin/glusterfs-client) which is newer, too? I doubt adding 12.04 repository will work well in 18.04.

Comment: Because we are running the `gluster server` with version `3.2.1` and it works with `gluster client` `3.2.5`, but not with the newest `gluster client` available for Ubuntu 18 (`3.13.2`) (everything with the same configuration)

Comment: You might try downloading the deb [from the repository](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glusterfs) and install manually or download the `tar.gz` and build by yourself if the `.deb` does not work.

Comment: I _started_ installing the `deb` manually, but they are tons of depedencies to download and install...

Answer (score 1):

I do not see serious problems.
You can install GlusterFS Client manually by downloading 3 deb-files to Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget https://mirrors.wikimedia.org/ubuntu/ubuntu/pool/main/f/fuse/fuse-utils_2.8.6-2ubuntu2_all.deb
sudo apt install ./fuse-utils_2.8.6-2ubuntu2_all.deb

wget https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/glusterfs/glusterfs-common_3.2.5-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./glusterfs-common_3.2.5-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb

wget https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/glusterfs/glusterfs-client_3.2.5-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./glusterfs-client_3.2.5-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

To prevent upgrading of glusterfs packages you need to pin/lock their versions with one long command:

```
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/pin-glusterfs
Package: glusterfs-common
Pin: version 3.2.5-1ubuntu1
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: glusterfs-client
Pin: version 3.2.5-1ubuntu1
Pin-Priority: 1337
EOF
```

This will end with:

> ```
> $ glusterfsd --version
> glusterfs 3.2.5 built on Jan 31 2012 07:39:58
> ...
>
> $ glusterfs --version
> glusterfs 3.2.5 built on Jan 31 2012 07:39:58
> ...
>
> $ mount.glusterfs --version
> glusterfs 3.2.5 built on Jan 31 2012 07:39:58
> ...
> ```

Please note that **these package will not receive security updates**.